# Conditional sql based on string content

Tags: php, foreach

How to judge an image url that if the link contains words `ads` `ad`, then pass insert into the database. Then it should be insert into first data, and pass the second one. Thanks,

PHP CODE

```
foreach($data['image'] as $item) {
  $title = $item['title'];
  $image = $item['image_url'];
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO article (title, image) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$image."')");
}
```

JSON TREE

```
{
    "image": [
        {
            "title": "the big lake",
            "image_url": "http://localhost/json/image/the_big_lake.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "Nike Air",
            "image_url": "http://localhost/json/image/12087689_ads.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your question is poorly worded.  I understand you want to detect the string "ad" in the `image_url` key, but I am not tracking what you want to do when such a condition is met.

Comment: @Chris, Whether I can use `if(preg_match)` to make a judge first?

Comment: I get that you want a **conditional** (not "judge"), but I am not certain what you want to do if the conditional is true.  So - if there is the string "ad" in the file name... do what?  Insert it?  Don't insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you want to insert all images that do NOT have "ad" in the image url... if you want ONLY ads, change the `===` in the if statement to a `!==`.  Make sure to keep it as either a triple-equals or exclamation-double-equals.

Also note that this is not a very reliable method - what if the image were called "my_dad_and_mom.jpg".  It contains "ad", but is not an ad.

```
foreach($data['image'] as $item) {
  if (strpos($item['image_url'], 'ad') === false) {
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); // not sure why this is needed....
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO article (title, image) VALUES ('".$item['title']."', '".$item['image_url']."')");
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** This is sort of quick and dirty...

```
    $forbidden_words = array(
        'ads',
        'ad',
        'sex',
        'xxx'
    );
    function str_in_array($str, $array) {
        foreach ($array as $token) {
            if (stristr($str, $token) !== FALSE)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
foreach($data['image'] as $item) {
  if (str_in_array($item['image_url'], $forbidden_words) === false) {
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); // not sure why this is needed....
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO article (title, image) VALUES ('".$item['title']."', '".$item['image_url']."')");
  }
}
```

Comment: Added an array of forbidden words, and a function to check

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
foreach($data['image'] as $item) {
  $title = $item['title'];
  $image = $item['image_url'];
  if(preg_match('/ad/',$image){
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO article (title, image) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$image."')");
  }
}
```

Comment: it should be `if(!preg_match('/ad/',$image)){`

Comment: "judge an image url that if the link contains words ads ad, then pass insert into the database" sounds like he wanted it the other way, that makes far more sense though;)

Comment: I know preg_match only allow one word match. but chris solve it by a function.

Comment: you also asked initially for something that rooted out 'ad' and 'ads'... in either case the word 'ad' would have been found... but chris has a more robust answer